# Home screen like facebook

Tags: android, android-activity, homescreen

How do I create a home screen like the one facebook and instagram uses, where a user can post pictures and content which are placed on the home screen for other users to see and like and comment on using java.

Comment: This is **way** too broad of a question to possibly be answered.  It's like asking "How do I create a car like Toyota and Ford."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you need an answer, so i'll try to give you one...
For that you have to learn basic android components such as viewPager, viewPagerAdaper as well as tablayout, coordinatorLayout, and many others stuff (recyclerView, jetpack libs such as Paging, Navigation component and more) and tech such as firebase (auth, db, cloud function....), google cloud or AWS.
As you can see it’s a whole journey
But you can start it with YouTube... i recomand you `coding with mitch` (he has a tutorial series where he builds an Instagram clone) or `coding in flow`.
About books i don’t really have one in mind but I hope this little answer helped.
Have a good day

Comment: THANX@ALEYAM THATS GONNA HELP ME A LOT THANX BRO